# React hooks and getStaticProps

Tags: authentication, next.js, react-hooks

I want to access `hooks` from `getStaticProps` to get the `accessToken` of the logged user which is saved in `AuthContext`. **but this is impossible**

I am using getStaticProps of Nextjs to pre-render pages, this is an example :

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const result = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/track/landing-tracks-for-admin");
  return {
    props: {
      tracks: result.data,
    },
    revalidate: 5,
  };
}
```

the problem is that this request needs the user accesToken which I can get from `useAuth`

```
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";
```

but when I try to call it in `getStaticProps` like this : `const auth = useAuth();`
I get this error

> React Hook "useAuth" is called in function "getStaticProps" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

any other alternatives ?

Comment: How are you logging your user? On the client? Can you show that part? Meanwhile, you cannot access a value with a hook in `getStaticProps`, as this function runs on the server, at build time.

Comment: Where Is that `accessToken` stored? In Local Storage or Cookie?

Comment: local storage but even if it was in cookie `getStaticProps` can't access to it too I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you cannot authenticate the user like this. Please follow the documentation on [Nextjs for authentication](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication).

There is also an example repository for static page authentication using [with-iron-session](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-iron-session).

I suggest that you implement the user Authentication the nextjs way since you are using nextjs

Comment: yes I guess that I should use nextjs session there is no other way